# How to reorder a data frame based on mean of column groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to reorder a data frame based on the median value associated with a column ID.

I have a dataframe with a column of IDs and 2 columns of values.

```
ID <- c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c")
alpha <- c(3,4,5,9,11,13,1,1,1,0)
beta <- c(2,3,4,3,4,5,4,5,6,7)
df <- data.frame(ID,alpha,beta)

   ID alpha beta
1   a     3    2
2   a     4    3
3   a     5    4
4   b     9    3
5   b    11    4
6   b    13    5
7   c     1    4
8   c     1    5
9   c     1    6
10  c     0    7
```

I want to reorder this dataframe so that the column ID is in an order based on the decending means of the associated values in the alpha column:

```
   ID alpha beta
1   b     9    3
2   b    11    4
3   b    13    5
4   a     3    2
5   a     4    3
6   a     5    4
7   c     1    4
8   c     1    5
9   c     1    6
10  c     0    7
```

This was unsuccessful:

```
df[reorder(df$ID, df$alpha, FUN = mean),]
```

Comment: You're very close but mixing up two ideas. `reorder` reorders the levels of the factor, which is good to do if you want the ordering to persist beyond just the row order of the data frame. I would do `df$ID = reorder(df$ID, df$alpha, FUN = mean)`. Then you can order the data frame by that column: `df[order(df$ID), ]`

Comment: @coffeinjunky Good point, but I still don't have enough credit to upvote yet ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(m = mean(alpha)) %>% arrange(desc(m)) %>% select(-m)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   ID [3]
       ID alpha  beta
   <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1      b     9     3
 2      b    11     4
 3      b    13     5
 4      a     3     2
 5      a     4     3
 6      a     5     4
 7      c     1     4
 8      c     1     5
 9      c     1     6
10      c     0     7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, mean(alpha), ID][order(-V1), .(ID)], on = .(ID)]
#    ID alpha beta
#1:  b     9    3
#2:  b    11    4
#3:  b    13    5
#4:  a     3    2
#5:  a     4    3
#6:  a     5    4
#7:  c     1    4
#8:  c     1    5
#9:  c     1    6
#10: c     0    7
```

---

Or we can use `ave` from `base R` to get the `mean` and then `order`

```
df[with(df, order(-ave(alpha, ID))),]
```