# Arrange groups in dplyr with aggregation function

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to order groups in a dplyr tibble by using an aggregation function. Let's say I have this data:

```r
library(dplyr)
df <- tibble(
  g = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
  x = c(0, 1, 1, 2, -2, -3, -3)
)
```

Where `g` is the grouping variable. If I want to sort using the mean of x, I would expect `g=2` observations be on top, then `g=0` and then `g=1`. The first thing that comes to mind is to:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>% 
  arrange(mean(x))
```

But this is not sorted the way I expected:

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   g [3]
      g     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0
2     0     1
3     1     1
4     1     2
5     2    -2
6     2    -3
7     2    -3
```

Instead, I would expect to have something like:

```r
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   g [3]
      g     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2    -2
2     2    -3
3     2    -3
4     0     0
5     0     1
6     1     1
7     1     2
```

is there a tidy way to do this operation?

Comment: You could try `df %>% 
 group_by(g) %>%
 arrange(group_by(., g) %>% mutate(across(x, mean)) %>% pull(x))`, but I'm not sure whether it would always work reliably.

Comment: `df[order(ave(df$x, df$g, FUN = mean)), ]`

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008444/how-to-reorder-a-data-frame-based-on-mean-of-column-groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
df %>% group_by(g) %>% mutate(m = mean(x)) %>% arrange(m) %>% select(-m)
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   g [3]
      g     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2    -2
2     2    -3
3     2    -3
4     0     0
5     0     1
6     1     1
7     1     2
```

Comment: This works indeed, I was looking for a more "automatic" way to do it, like a function. Do you think a general function can be extracted from your pipeline in here?

Comment: hmmm exact same code as the accepted answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46008444/how-to-reorder-a-data-frame-based-on-mean-of-column-groups

Answer (score 1):

You can get the order in which you want to arrange the data.

```
order_vec <- names(sort(tapply(df$x, df$g, mean)))
order_vec
#[1] "2" "0" "1"
```

And then can use `dplyr::arrange` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(match(g, order_vec))

#      g     x
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2    -2
#2     2    -3
#3     2    -3
#4     0     0
#5     0     1
#6     1     1
#7     1     2
```

Or base R subsetting :

```
df[order(match(df$g, order_vec)), ]
```